# Is there any media player (except VLC) that allows to define the start and stop time of a played file?

Tags: media-player, portable

The famous VLC player has an especially useful feature - setting start/stop time of a media, but this player has some annoying bugs (no way to shuffle the playlist, an unexpected, user-unfriendly [direct 3d output window](https://superuser.com/questions/441233/vlc-opening-direct-3d-output-windows)), so I'd like to see some alternative. Do you know such a player? I've read something about GOM player, maybe it has something like this, but I didn't use it because that app doesn't seem to have a portable version.
If you know such a player, but it has no portable version, anyway, post its name in a comment/answer, it will be useful info...

Comment: Since VLC is Open Source, you *could* work at fixing the bugs you dislike...or check if they even still exist; the link you point to is from 2012 and references Windows XP.